# Using PHP + TAR to extract a folder

Tags: php, tar

I would like to automate downloading the latest WordPress version to the root folder of the webserver. Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp.tar.gz', 'w+');
$ch = curl_init('http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
exec('tar -zxvf wp.tar.gz wordpress');
unlink('wp.tar.gz');
?>
```

The problem is, that the WordPress tar file contains a directory /wordpress which contains all the files, so after running this PHP file I now have a /wordpress directory which contains the files, but instead of everything in /wordpress, i want it to be in / (from where the PHP file runs). Or should I use the 'mv' command to move everything from /wordpress to / ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a new enough version of GNU or BSD tar:

```
exec('tar -zxvf --strip-components=1 wp.tar.gz wordpress');
```

By the way, if you have no need for the list of extracted files, you do not need the `v` option.

See also: [How do I extract a specific directory from a tarball? and strip a leading directory?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3786/how-do-i-extract-a-specific-directory-from-a-tarball-and-strip-a-leading-direct)

Answer (score 1):

```
Why dont you use this : 
http://wordpress.org/latest.zip

Then your code would look like:

<?php
$filename = "http://wordpress.org/latest.zip";
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$latestzip_file = 'latest.zip';
$fh = fopen($latestzip_file, 'w') or die("can't open file");
fwrite($fh, $contents);
fclose($fh);
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open($latestzip_file);
if($res === TRUE)
{
      $zip->extractTo(dirname(__FILE__));       // Extract to the main directory //
  $zip->close();
      unlink($latestzip_file);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding  `--strip=1`  opt

```
  tar xvzf wp.tar.gz --strip=1
```